# replaceWith includes a string and not an html element

Tags: html, jquery

I try to replace an html element by a new html element which has been computed and returned by twig. But the replaceWith function understands it as a string and not an html element

```
function replaceItem(item, html) {
    item?.replaceWith(html);
}
```

Before replaceItem
[image]
After replaceItem
[image]

[image]

Sometime partialy worked
[image]

Have try this :

```
function replaceItem(item, html) {
    newItem = create.element(html);
    item?.replaceWith(newItem);
}

function replaceItem(item, html) {
    item?.replaceWith(html).html();
}
```

Comment: What you want is probably [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `item` is a DOM element, you're calling the DOM method, not the jQuery method. The DOM version doesn't interpret HTML, it treats it as literal text.

So use the jQuery method:

```
function replaceItem(item, html) {
    if (item) {
        $(item).replaceWith(html);
    }
}
```